# ScaffoldMessenger showSnackBar on Navigator.push or .pop?

Tags: flutter, dart

As simple as it sounds, what's the current method to display a snackbar through the `ScaffoldMessenger` after a Navigator.pop into the previous page, where the snackbar is shown on the now current page (previous)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return data to the first screen, use the Navigator.pop() method and then show snackbar

```
  ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Close the screen and return "test!" as the result.
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
                ..showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('test')));
            },
            child: const Text('close!'),
          )
```

For more read this [article](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/returning-data)

Comment: This worked perfectly! Had to check out the article though.

Answer (score 0):

first show the snackbar using
`ScaffoldMessenger.of(context) ..hideCurrentSnackBar() ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));`
and later you can use
`Navigator.pop();`

Answer (score 0):

```
content: Text(response['message']),
  backgroundColor: primaryColor,
  dismissDirection: DismissDirection.up,
);
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
Navigator.of(context).pop()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.